# Deadlock found in Ejabberd Query

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-saas

When I try to create and add participant in Ejabberd MIX Module I got the error "#40001Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

EX:
SQL query 'INSERT INTO mix_subscription(channel, service, username, domain, node, jid) VALUES ('omqmphlhmdjktgijerrxlbgrh', 'mix.localhost', '123', 'localhost', 'urn:xmpp:mix:nodes:messages', '123@localhost');' failed: "#40001Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"